# Unable to access my site on ec2 instance aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, hosting

I deployed a web app on an ec2 instance AWS.
I am unable to view my site on a web browser. The site does not load at all, just shows an empty screen.

Please see my inbound rules, perhaps there is something I did not add. I'll appreciate any help.

[image]

After running netstat, I get the following response:

[image]

Comment: did you run your site? Or just copy-pasted files?

Comment: yes I ran it.. my site actually opens on my chrome browser only, but I cannot access it via any other browser

Comment: which port your site using? How can you check that it is running?

Comment: i ran netstat, and I attached a screenshot of the response. Im using nginx for my site on the ec2 instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an AWS issue.

Your React App has a problem:

[image]